# List Last Successful Software Installed On A Computer

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, inventory

Am looking to list the last successful software installed on a computer. And, I would like to sort it by most recent date. Below, Am sharing the code that seems to work on querying all software; however, I cannot get to select the most recent successful ones.

```
gp 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*',  
   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*' |
  Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
  Sort-Object InstallDate -descending |
  Where-Object {$_.InstallDate -gt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Sort-Object InstallDate -descending |
    Where-Object {
        $_.InstallDate -gt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-5).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    }
```

Note changes to your code snippet:

- a backslash before ending ˙*˙ wildcard in both `HKLM: … \Uninstall\*` registry paths;
- `(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(3)` points to a date in the future;
- you can't compare a date object with the `InstallDate` property which is a string formatted using the `yyyyMMdd` pattern (but not always as shown in the following example from my system):

> ```
> DisplayName                DisplayVersion Publisher          InstallDate
> -----------                -------------- ---------          -----------
> Java 8 Update 211 (64-bit) 8.0.2110.12    Oracle Corporation 20190427
> Java Auto Updater          2.8.211.12     Oracle Corporation 20190427
> Java 8 Update 211          8.0.2110.12    Oracle Corporation 20190427
> XAMPP                      7.2.12-0       Bitnami            1544357402
> ```

Comment: To get the installdate right for applications like XAMPP, that write a Unix timestamp instead of a date in `yyyyMMdd` format, you could add a calculated property to the `Select-Object`. Something like this perhaps: `Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, @{ Name = 'InstallDate'; Expression = { if ($_.InstallDate.Length -gt 8) {[DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds($_.InstallDate).LocalDateTime } else {$_.InstallDate}}}`

Comment: @Theo thanks for deep insight but the `$_.InstallDate` is `Int32` type (not having the `Length` property) for `XAMPP`. Hence, the `if` condition should be formulated in another (more sophisticated) way. Moreover, `$_.InstallDate` could be missing (or even empty) for some software.  However, this exceeds the OQ topic (IMHO).